# Exporting from Access Database (.mdb) via Python to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, database, ms-access, mdbtools

I'm looking for a method to programmatically access an access database file (.mdb) using python in an Ubuntu environment (hosted on a Windows 10 machine) to export tables to pandas dataframes.
I've attempted the solutions previously posted, such as using pandas access, pyodbc, or mdbtools, however all have failed due to errors relating to missing tables or files in the packages.

Any feedback or insights would be much appreciated!

pyodc failure:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 pypyodbc.lowercase = False
----> 2 conn = pypyodbc.connect(
      3     r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
      4     r"/home/kevin/scratch/HDINEWTON.mdb;")
      5 cur = conn.cursor()
      6 # cur.execute("SELECT CreatureID, Name_EN, Name_JP FROM Creatures");
      7 # while True:
      8 #     row = cur.fetchone()
   (...)
     11 #     print(u"Creature with ID {0} is {1} ({2})".format(
     12 #         row.get("CreatureID"), row.get("Name_EN"), row.get("Name_JP")))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py:2454, in Connection.__init__(self, connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly, **kargs)
   2450 if self.connection_timeout != 0:
   2451     self.set_connection_timeout(connection_timeout)
-> 2454 self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py:2507, in Connection.connect(self, connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
   2505 else:
   2506     ret = odbc_func(self.dbc_h, 0, c_connectString, len(self.connectString), None, 0, None, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
-> 2507 check_success(self, ret)
   2510 # Set the connection's attribute of "autocommit" 
   2511 #
   2512 self.autocommit = autocommit

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py:1009, in check_success(ODBC_obj, ret)
   1007     ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
   1008 elif isinstance(ODBC_obj, Connection):
-> 1009     ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
   1010 else:
   1011     ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, ODBC_obj, ret, False)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py:983, in ctrl_err(ht, h, val_ret, ansi)
    981     raise NotSupportedError(state,err_text)
    982 elif state in (raw_s('HYT00'),raw_s('HYT01'),raw_s('01000')):
--> 983     raise OperationalError(state,err_text)
    984 elif state[:2] in (raw_s('IM'),raw_s('HY')):
    985     raise Error(state,err_text)

OperationalError: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' : file not found")
```

pandas access failure:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 2
      1 path_to_mdb_database = '/home/kevin/scratch/HDINEWTON.mdb'
----> 2 mdb.list_tables(path_to_mdb_database)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas_access/__init__.py:25, in list_tables(rdb_file, encoding)
     17 def list_tables(rdb_file, encoding="latin-1"):
     18     """
     19     :param rdb_file: The MS Access database file.
     20     :param encoding: The content encoding of the output. I assume `latin-1`
   (...)
     23     :return: A list of the tables in a given database.
     24     """
---> 25     tables = subprocess.check_output(['mdb-tables', rdb_file]).decode(encoding)
     26     return tables.strip().split(" ")

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:465, in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    462         empty = b''
    463     kwargs['input'] = empty
--> 465 return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    466            **kwargs).stdout

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:546, in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    543     kwargs['stdout'] = PIPE
    544     kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
--> 546 with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    547     try:
    548         stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1022, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize, process_group)
   1018         if self.text_mode:
   1019             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
   1020                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
-> 1022     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   1023                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
   1024                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
   1025                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1026                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1027                         errread, errwrite,
   1028                         restore_signals,
   1029                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
   1030                         start_new_session, process_group)
   1031 except:
   1032     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
   1033     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb_access/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1899, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session, process_group)
   1897     if errno_num != 0:
   1898         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1899     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1900 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mdb-tables'
```

mdb tools failure:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 5
      3 import os
      4 import pandas_access as mdb
----> 5 import mdbtools
      7 print('Imports Successful')

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mdbtools/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .MDBcli import *
      2 from .MDBnetrc import *
      3 from .MDBtool import *

File ~/miniconda3/envs/mdb/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mdbtools/MDBcli.py:21
     19 import sys
     20 import argparse
---> 21 from MDButils import *
     23 # Stop Python from complaining when I/O pipes are closed
     24 from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MDButils'
```

Comment: So do the tables or files or modules actually exist?

Comment: Others have had success using pandas_access and mdbtools right out of the box, so I would believe so. I previewed the database tables in excel as well so I know they're not corrupted and do in fact exist.